# Configure Tabs for ion-tabs at Root Level

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routing, ionic4

I am looking for help with configuring `ion-tabs` so the tabs are at root level instead of needing a subfolder. So instead of `/tabs/tab1` I want `/tab1`.

I am following a combination of [Ionic Academy](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-routing-navigation/) and the documentation for [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs) and [Angular Router](https://angular.io/guide/router#routing--navigation).

I am using the default setup that you get when you run `ionic start myApp tabs`.

The most likely is updating `tabs.router.module.ts` but not sure if/how it's possible. Here is the code from there.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'check-in',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../pages/check-in/check-in.module#CheckInPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'house-manual',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../pages/house-manual/house-manual.module#HouseManualPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'local-area',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../pages/local-area/local-area.module#LocalAreaPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/check-in',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/check-in',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

My latest attempt is this in app-routing.module, but when I change `path: 'tabs'` to `path: ''` it breaks with `ERROR Error: "[object Object]"` in the console.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {TabsPage} from './tabs/tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'check-in',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: './pages/check-in/check-in.module#CheckInPageModule'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'house-manual',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: './pages/house-manual/house-manual.module#HouseManualPageModule'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'local-area',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: './pages/local-area/local-area.module#LocalAreaPageModule'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/check-in',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/check-in',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: all you need to do, is just move the routing from tabs.router.module to app router module

Comment: Thanks, sounds good

Comment: @VarunSukheja I tried this every way I can think of, but can't get it to work, and the error messages are not helpful. For example, what happens to the `component: TabsPage` if it is moved to app-rouing.module.ts? Can you provide more information as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I studied the [Router documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes) and moved the router config to app-router, but when I change `path: 'tabs'` to `path: ''` it breaks with `ERROR Error: "[object Object]"` in the console.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to achieve this, just add the following attributes in your tabs buttons on your page tabs.page.html

```
routerLink="/tab1" routerDirection="root"
```

Example

```
    <ion-tabs>

      <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
        <ion-tab-button routerLink="/tab1" routerDirection="root" tab="tab1">
          <ion-icon name="flash"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Tab One</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button routerLink="/tab2" routerDirection="root"  tab="tab2">
          <ion-icon name="apps"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Tab Two</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button routerLink="/tab3" routerDirection="root"  tab="tab3">
          <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Tab Three</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
      </ion-tab-bar>

    </ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try this soon.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I've found (ionic 4):

.ts:

```
    private selectedTab;

constructor(
    public translations: TranslationsService,
    private navCtrl: NavController
) {
}

async setCurrentTab() {
    this.selectedTab = this.tabs.getSelected();
    await this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('tabs/' + this.selectedTab);
}
```

.html:

```
<ion-tabs #tabs (ionTabsDidChange)="setCurrentTab()">
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="home">
      <ion-icon class="neosurf-color" src='{{getIcon("home")}}'  id="home"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label class="neosurf-color">{{translations.__('global.home')}}</ion-label>n-icon class="neosurf-color" src='{{getIcon("locator")}}' id="locator"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label class="neosurf-color">{{translations.__('global.locator')}}</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>n-icon class="neosurf-color" src='{{getIcon("locator")}}' id="locator"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label class="neosurf-color">{{translations.__('global.locator')}}</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
```

good luck!